# mail function is not working on bigrock hosting?

Tags: php, email

I am using php mail function which is working fine godaddy linux hosting but it is not working on bigrock linux hosting , also mail function is availble ,

```
    <?

      $mailto="me@gmail.com";  //Enter recipient email address here

       $subject = "Test Email";

       $from="info@mydomain.com";          

       $message_body = "This is a test email from Webmaster.";

       if(mail($mailto,$subject,$message_body,"From:".$from)){
            echo "Your email has been sent successfully";
       }
       else{
            echo "email not send ";

       }


?>
<?php 
if (function_exists('mail')) { 
    echo 'mail() is available'; 
} else { 
    echo 'mail() has been disabled'; }
?>
```

Comment: What do you see? What don't you see? What's in the logs? etc etc.

Comment: I see email not send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigRock has significantly changed automated email handling in their hosting packages in the past few years in response to the increasing spam incidents. They now require you to explicitly register all email ids used by your scripts using their cPanel plugin.
They deny all automated emails from all email addresses except those white-listed by the said process.

Read more about it in the official knowledge base **[here](https://manage.bigrock.in/kb/answer/2880)**.

> We have enabled a tool that restricts the email IDs which can be used
>   for sending emails through scripts, to prevent spamming. In case you
>   wish to use an email address to send an email using the PHP mail
>   function, please ensure to register it in the cPanel.

This snippet was taken from their knowledge base